# $4\frac{x^3}{y^2}+\frac{3}{y}+\left(3\frac{x}{y^2}+4y\right)y' = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\underbrace{4\frac{x^3}{y^2}+\frac{3}{y}}_M+\underbrace{\left(3\frac{x}{y^2}+4y\right)}_Ny' = 0$$

In order to solve this equation, I want to transform it to an exact equation. I need to multiply it by a $\phi$ that depends only on $x$ or $y$, because I've not learned yet how to solve with both. Before trying with $\phi(y)$ or $\phi(x)$ we test these two things:

$$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}, \frac{M_y-N_x}{M}$$
if the first is dependent on only one variable, then I use $\phi(x)$, if it's the other, then $\phi(y)$.

$$M_y = 4\frac{-2x^3}{y^3}-\frac{3}{y^2}$$

$$N_x = 3\frac{1}{y^2}$$

Then:

$$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N} = \frac{\frac{-8x^3}{y^3}-\frac{3}{y^2}-\frac{3}{y^2}}{3\frac{x}{y^2}+4y}$$

$$\frac{M_y-N_x}{M} = \frac{\frac{-8x^3}{y^3}-\frac{3}{y^2}-\frac{3}{y^2}}{4\frac{x^3}{y^2}+\frac{3}{y}}$$

I can't see any of them to depend only on one variable. Can you?

Comment: You lost an $x^3$ when you computed $M_y.$ Second, divide by $M$, not $M_y$.

Comment: @B.Goddard thanks, I corrected that

Comment: OK, now factor $-2/y$ out of the numerator and your last fraction simplifes to a function of $y$ alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by multiplying both sides  to ${ y }^{ 2 }\\ \\ $ we can get quite an  easy solution
$$ \left( 4x^{ 3 }+3y \right) dx+\left( 3x+4{ y }^{ 3 } \right) dy=0\\ 4\left( { x }^{ 3 }dx+{ y }^{ 3 }dy \right) +3\left( ydx+xdy \right) =0\\ 4d\left( { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } \right) +3d\left( xy \right) =0\\ 4\left( { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } \right) +3xy=C$$